# How to return Node.js callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback, mongoose

I have a node.js method that using mongoose in order to return some data, the problem is that since I'm using a callback inside my method nothing is being returned to the client

my code is:

```
var getApps = function(searchParam){
    var appsInCategory = Model.find({ categories: searchParam});
    appsInCategory.exec(function (err, apps) {
        return apps;
    });
}
```

If I'm trying to do it synchronously by using a json object for example it will work:

```
var getApps = function(searchParam){
    var appsInCategory = JSONOBJECT;
    return appsInCategory
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return from a callback - see [this canonical about the fundamental problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). Since you're working with Mongoose you can return a promise for it though:

```
var getApps = function(searchParam){
    var appsInCategory = Model.find({ categories: searchParam});
    return appsInCategory.exec().then(function (apps) {
        return apps; // can drop the `then` here
    });
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
getApps().then(function(result){
    // handle result here
});
```